# Cut string and gunzip using PHP

Tags: php, zlib

I have a router config export file, which contains a header of 20 bytes, followed by zlib compressed data.  Once uncompressed it should contain plain xml content.

My code strips the first 20 bytes, and decompresses the file.  The exported data is still binary.  I used file_get_contents and file_put_contents first, but assumed (wrongly) it wasn't binary-safe. I've tried to change the 20 in anything from 1-1000 without avail.

```
<?
$fp_orig        = fopen('config.cfg', "rb");
$data_orig      = fread($fp_orig, filesize('config.cfg'));
fclose($fp_orig);

$bytes          = 20;  // tried 1-1000 
$data_gz        = substr($data_orig,$bytes);

$fp_gz          = fopen('config.cfg.gz', 'w');
fwrite($fp_gz, $data_gz);
fclose($fp_gz);

$fp_gz          = gzopen('config.cfg.gz', 'rb');
$fp_xml         = fopen('config.cfg.xml', 'wb'); 
while(!gzeof($fp_gz))
{
  fwrite($fp_xml, gzread($fp_gz, 4096));
}
fclose($fp_xml);
gzclose($fp_gz);

echo file_get_contents('config.cfg.xml'); // gives binary data
?>
```

I'm not particularly looking for turnkey working code, but rather a push into the right direction.

Comment: If you're on *NIX, you could try `dd if=config.cfg of=config.cfg.gz ibs=20 skip=1` to rule out a problem in the PHP code.

Comment: @Kenney what was I thinking - `dd` would have saved me time from the beginning.  `dd` also doesn't return a valid .gz file.  Back to the drawing board :-(

Comment: You could check for the offset for the gzip magic constant: 0x1f, 0x8b. It might even be at offset 0..

Comment: Turned out it was a zlib file (78 9c) and not a gzip (1f 8b) file.  `echo gzuncompress(substr(file_get_contents('config.cfg'),20));` now does print the correct xml content.